# Could not verify whether account has right permissions while configuring test agent tfs 2010

Tags: controller

I am trying to configure test agent on a windows 7 machine. My account is under local administrators group. But still keep giving me error that could not verify whether the account under which the test agent is running has the right permission to connect to test controller. ......rerun the utility under an account that has local administrator privileges on test controller.

Also showing Test Agent status as Disconnected..Please see the following from log file

```
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:42.604, Machine Name: DEV
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:42.604, Final Domain: COM.  Final username: COM/sam
E, 2012/02/02, 12:08:42.645, Got an exception in HandleUserAccountChangeForProcess    at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.ExecutionUtilities.AddUser(DirectoryEntry userToAdd, DirectoryEntry computer, String groupName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.TestControllerHelper.AddUserAccount(ServiceAccount account, String groupName, String machineName, Boolean useRemoteName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.TestControllerHelper.AddAgentAccountToControllerGroup(ServiceAccount agentServiceAccount, String controllerUri)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.AgentConfiguration.HandleUserAccountChangeForProcess(AgentConfigurationUpdatePack updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)
E, 2012/02/02, 12:08:42.645, PreviousProcessAccount = COM\samCurrentProcessAccount = COM\sam
W, 2012/02/02, 12:08:42.646, Could not verify whether the account under which the test       agent is running has the right permissions to connect to the test controller. If the test agent is unable to connect to the controller, then rerun this utility under an account that has local administrator privileges on the test controller machine.
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:42.646, Configuring ACL...
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.620, Configured ACL successfully.
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.621, Stopping test agent process...
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.630, Test agent process stopped successfully.
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.632, Checking whether account COM\sam is a network service account or not
V, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.633, Created Nt account COM\sam for userName COM\sam
V, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.633, Found Sid S-1-5-21-3822552688-3526577868-2225499705-1308 for userName COM\sam
I, 2012/02/02, 12:08:56.633, Observed that account COM\sam is network service account? False
```

Any Idea what's going wrong.